# replace multiple find selectors in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have multiple $find() selectors. Could it be used as object literal or chaining to see if it could be replaced to speed up the performance.

```
var i = $('#some-id');
$i.find('#itemno1').html('item1');
$i.find('#itemno2').html('item2');
$i.find('#itemno3').html('item3');  //...more find selectors to continue
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find elements in one `find` call with comma separated input , like below -

```
var i = $('#some-id');
$i.find('#itemno1, #itemno2, #itemno3').html('item1');
```

Comment: @davyvson: do you mean like $i.find('#itemno1, #itemno2').html('item1','item2');

Comment: just for search you can do that, to set `html` you will have to loop